# Convert (compress) JPEG images using mogrify keeping the original files in the same directory

Tags: images, compression, imagemagick, xubuntu, mogrify

I'm trying to convert(compress) a bunch of JPEG images using imagemagick command mogrify, keeping the original file in the same directory.
I'm typing in terminal window : mogrify -quality 25% *.JPEG con-%002d.JPEG then I get the error : mogrify: unable to open image `con-%002d.JPEG': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
How can I solve this error? I have run : identify -verbose * | grep Format and the result is for all files : Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormat: 10718
    exif:thumbnail:JPEGInterchangeFormatLength: 8223

My system is Xubuntu 16.04, I appreciate some help, thanks Vladi.

Comment: `mogrify` doesn't have an output file option: it always replaces the original files, and `con-%002d.JPEG` is treated as just another input file (which doesn't exist) after the `*.JPEG` list.

Comment: What kind of output name are you looking for? Sequential numbering?

Comment: @chewsocks I read some where(I don't remember where) that I could compress a JPEG file given an output file name which not replace the original file. The output name could be a sequential number or something like con-001.JPEG, con-002.JPEG, con-003.JPEG, ....

Comment: You may have been thinking of `ffmpeg` which does support sequential output naming.

Comment: @chewsocks No, I'm not wrong, it is on imagemagick mogrify command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the man page `mogrify`  does not take an output option, it simply overwrites the input file unless the format is changed (the same name is used up to the file extension).

Try this using `convert` instead.

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
for i in *.JPEG; do 
    convert "$i" -format jpg -quality '25%' $(printf con-%03d.JPEG $n)
    n=$((n+1))
done
```

---

### JPEG vs jpg

I mogrified the same image twice

```
$ mogrify -format JPEG b.jpg
$ mogrify -format jpg b.jpg
```

Then

```
$ diff -u <(identify -verbose b.jpg ) <(identify -verbose b.JPEG)
--- /dev/fd/63  2018-09-29 14:42:27.506462707 -0400
+++ /dev/fd/62  2018-09-29 14:42:27.510462929 -0400
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Image: b.jpg
+Image: b.JPEG
@@ -71,2 +71,2 @@
-    date:create: 2018-09-29T14:37:11-04:00
-    date:modify: 2018-09-29T14:37:11-04:00
+    date:create: 2018-09-29T14:37:03-04:00
+    date:modify: 2018-09-29T14:37:03-04:00
@@ -77 +77 @@
-    filename: b.jpg
+    filename: b.JPEG
```

Comment: OK!! That's done the job. Thanks. Can I ask what's the difference between JPEG format and jpg fomat ? The script above converts to "jpg" then the new file output is saved as ".JPEG" what's the hack? thanks

Comment: @vladimirpavloski Good question...habit =P. I avoid capitals in my names so I always think of the format as "jpg". `convert` doesn't enforce file extensions (you could save JPEG as .txt) and since I was being specific I saw you liked "JPEG".

Answer (score 0):

### Use `-write`

```
mogrify -set filename:name '%t_q%Q' -quality 30 -write '%[filename:name].jpg' *.jpg
```

Above command will write the converted image to a new name: converting **name.jpg** to **name_q30.jpg**, **name1.jpg** to **name1_q30.jpg**. Keeping your old files safe.

For other *percentage escape* metadata options, see the [docs](http://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php)